# Passing parameter with @html.beginform and dropdownlist to controller

Tags: asp.net, view, controller, viewmodel

I have problem to submit a parameter to a controller. I want one of the parameters to the controller to be injected with the value from the dropdownlist.

code:

```
  @Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserNewsdesk","UserList", new { id = Model.Id , newsdeskId = VALUE FROM LIST}, FormMethod.Post)        
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.List, Model.List)
        }
```

code for controller getting injected:

```
public ActionResult ChangeUserNewsdesk(Guid id, string newsdeskId)
 {

 }
```

**The list shows up fine but i need to add a button and when its clicked, populate newsdeskId with the correct value from the Dropdownlist.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm confused. Why can't you just have the button's action be creating a new desk? If you update the Model's list, the new data should be brought back and bound to your list correctly.

Comment: Can you give me a example or link, please!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that one of the parameters will be send automatacly with the name as the left parameter and can be easily mapped in the controller.

In example:

**View**

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("ChangeUserNewsdesk","UserList", new { id = Model.Id}, FormMethod.Post)
{   
@Html.DropDownListFor("newsdeskName", Model.List)
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ChangeUserNewsdesk(Guid id,string newsdeskName){

}
```

The value newsdeskName will contain the corresponding model.list text and will be sent to and match as newsdeskName.